# Can Ext-GWT animate the window minimize-down event?

Tags: animation, gxt

Looking at the [web desktop sample for Ext-JS](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html) I see that when a window is minimized or restored, that there is an animation where a transparent rectangle shrinks down to the task bar or grows up to the window location.

When I look at the same demo for [Ext-GWT](http://www.extjs.com/examples/desktop.html) there is no animation: the window just vanishes and reappears.

Is there a way to turn this animation on for Ext-GWT, and what is the code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it.  The catch is that you have to

- catch the minimize event
- replace your rendered window with a proxy
- simultaneously move and resize your proxy
- replace your final proxy with the button on the dock bar

I'd consider following the extjs implementation as a guide.

The fact that it isn't represented as a demo suggests that it takes quite a bit of work to put it together.

Comment: That is my concern, that it will take quite a bit of work. I'll take a look at the extjs implementation. But it doesn't seem like there is a lot of similarity between extjs code and extgwt code.